# Micro optimization: Returning from an inner block at the end of a function

Tags: javascript, micro-optimization

In languages such as javascript or (maybe?) lua, all functions by default are treated as if they had a `return` statement at the end:

```
function() {
    // do
    return;
}
```

Is equal to

```
function() {
    // do
}
```

I'm wondering if returning from an inner block at the end of the function changes anything in the core, the compiling process, the VM.

```
function() {
    if (condition) {
        return;
    }

    // end of function
}
```

Same question applies to breaking a loop:

```
function() {
    for ( loop ) {
        return;
    }

    // end of function
}
```

Does the machine "look" for anything when a loop is broken, or a condition check has ended?

This is not a stylistic question, please don't tell me to make code readable.

Comment: @Thomas: it's about micro-optimization.  Read the tags.

Comment: FYI, the answer doesn't depend much on the language syntax.  All imperative languages that have syntax like this are essentially the same for this. It can depend on an interpreted vs. compiled (ahead-of-time or JIT) implementation, as far as being able to optimize an `if()break;` into something equivalent to an early return directly.

Comment: @PeterCordes I never mentioned syntax, I don't understand why you brought it up with this comment. My question is about interpreted languages (including runtime compilation). I mentioned JS because it's a popular one

Comment: I was commenting because you said you weren't sure about LUA syntax.  I meant to say that the answer is basically the same across pretty much all imperative languages, with possible differences breaking down by implementation strategy, not by language.  (Some languages have multiple implementations, e.g. CPython, Cython, PyPy).  And BTW, JS is usually JIT-compiled not just interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL:DR / optimization advice: you don't need to do anything special to gain performance.  `if(condition) return` inside an inner loop is typically at least as efficient as an `if(condition)break;` to reach the end of the function.

Putting nested loops inside a function so you can use a `return` as a multi-level `break` is a good way of being able to express the logic efficiently without a `goto`, easy for humans and easy for compilers/interpreters.

Making loop conditions more complicated to avoid multiple `return` statements in one function is not helpful for performance.

---

**Generally no, a `return` in the middle of a function is not fundamentally different or more or less efficient than reaching the implicit return at the end.**  And an explicit return at the *bottom* of a function isn't special either.

(We're talking about void functions that never return a value, I assume.  Obviously returning a value is different from not returning a value.)

Restructuring your code to `break` out of a loop and reach the implicit `return` at the bottom of a function is not more efficient (but could easily be *less* efficient in some interpreted languages, especially if they aren't JITed.)  e.g. if the interpreter does a jump within the function and then has to do another jump.  (A good ahead-of-time compiler or JIT optimizer could see what was happening and make good machine code anyway.)

Some compilers / interpreters may handle a `return` by just jumping to a common block of cleanup (epilogue) that all `return` statements share.  **But tail-duplication is possible**: when compiled to machine code, a function can have multiple copies of epilogue + `ret` instructions, reachable from different paths.

(JavaScript implementations *do* typically JIT functions to machine code; IDK about LUA.  And of course they can inline functions.  `return` statements in functions that get inlined can be just plain jumps, or could get optimized away entirely.)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Do you happen to know any way of testing such small changes? Or where such implementation would be located in the source code of a language, so I can try to figure something out?

Comment: @JohnSmith: For a JIT-compiled language like JS, you can look at the resulting machine code.  (This is possible for V8 using node.js, for example).  For Python, you can look at the bytecode.  (The CPython interpreter basically interprets this directly.)  But really, IDK why you'd want to think too hard about this; the clear way to write code is often the most efficient.  You don't need to avoid early return.

Comment: I'm not thinking hard about this. It's just something I wondered, and asked. It would be something I would keep in my mind in the future, but I'm not attached to it

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure whether I correctly understood your question, but I'll try to answer it from my point of view.

The `return` statement in the end of a function declaration indicates to leave the function and return nothing (*void*). If you omit a `return` statement, nothing would happen after the actual function execution. Thus, I think the two functions you declared behave in a different way:

```
function a() {
    // executes until the following statement and then breaks
    return;
}

function b() {
    // executes all statements and afterwards leaves the context where it was called
}
```

Regarding your question concerning inner blocks like condition checks or loops, I guess these statements could only be "optimized" by a parser somehow if they consist of static values like numbers or strings. As soon as any dynamic values like variables occur, it would be impossible to optimize anything or have an advantage from the inner `result` statement.

I hope you can get the point of my explanation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `return;`, `return undefined;` and _no return_ all behave the same way in javascript; not so sure about lua. If you do think they are different, could you show an example of it? I don't understand what you mean by "conditions consisting of static values".